# Upload photos only from recursive folders into Amazon Prime Cloud Drive via Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, upload

Does anyone know of an intelligent way to upload only photo file types into Amazon Prime Cloud Drive from one folder recursively using Windows 8.1?

Phrased another way: I have one folder with many folders inside it. Each internal folder has some photo file types, and some non photo types (zips, txt files, etc). I want to upload only the photos in each folder into Amazon Prime's Cloud Drive to take advantage of the free storage for Amazon Prime users.

I have considered copying photos only to new destination and uploading that new folder. Cygwin should be able to do this pretty easily via wildcards. But this seems like an inefficient solution. Anything better?